# A antimatter asteroid crashes into the Earth: Will a halo of γ rays protect the asteroid long enough to make it through the atmosphere?

Tags: antimatter

This question comes from an interesting [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/160592/63172) I received on Worldbuilding SE. The idea being that a fast moving antimatter object will react with the air molecules and produce gamma rays. These gamma rays will form a protective shield around the asteroid keeping any new air molecules from approaching the surface in a way similar to the [Leidenfrost_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect). This is the same idea that a micro black hole can't accumulate any new infalling matter due to the intense Hawking Radiation blasting out from it.

My question is: Is this a valid interpretation and if so, how long will this protective "shield" allow the 1 Ton asteroid to fly through the atmosphere. Will it explode safely up in the outer reach of the atmosphere or will it make it to the Earth's surface causing a devastating 39,000 megaton explosion? (Let's assume it's solid enough that it doesn't just break apart from heat stress)

Comment: I don't really see much we can add to the WorldBuilding discussion. It is hard to know if any of these answers left out something important. The XKCD answer is likely the best.

Comment: It seems odd to cross-post a question on another SE site in order to ask whether the answers found on the original SE site were correct. The answer on WorldBuilding by willk just seems like nonsense to me. It has no calculations to support it.

Comment: Note that *matter* asteroids tend to explode in the atmosphere, and most of their material is vaporized rather than reaching the ground. A good example is the ton-scale bolide that burst over Chelyabinsk in 2013.